# What is wrong with this TypeScript 2 Angular 2 code?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs

This is my first foray into TypeScript or Angular 2, and I am following the blog [Starting Angular 2 in ASP.NET Core with TypeScript using Visual Studio 2015](http://www.mithunvp.com/angular-2-in-asp-net-5-typescript-visual-studio-2015/)
by Mithun Pattankar.

In Step 7, he finally introduces some TypeScript:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: '<h3>My First Angular 2 App</h3>'
})
export class AppComponent { }
```

The main complaint, indicated by a red squiqgle under the 1st 'c' of `Component`,and when I hover over it, the editor displays a message saying the symbol cannot be fully resolved. Yet, I see no `Angular2` directories of code anywhere. I had asumed that somewhere in all the JSON he has one post into a project, there is a CDN or something. Angular seems to be simply missing, but I don't know how to properly introduce it into this project structure.

Comment: source code: https://github.com/mithunvp/Angular2AspNetCoreDemo